# How to use brew service to start Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, homebrew

I am using `brew` to install tomcat, so far so good.

I heard that I could use brew services to start tomcat as a service, but it failed when I try

```
brew services start tomcat
```

I received the error

```
Error: Formula `tomcat` has not implemented #plist or installed a locatable .plist file
```

I am wondering how to fix this?

Comment: You need to ask the brew folks to make Tomcat into a service-aware formula.

Comment: it is weird that tomcat not as a service

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Better: do it yourself and make a pull-request.

Comment: I've used `brew` for years and never knew it had a service infrastructure. Tomcat is complicated enough (e.g. multi-instance) that making an out-of-the-box service for it might not be terribly useful. It's not like using `curl`.

Answer (score 16):

The tomcat formula is now able to start and stop tomcat with:

```
brew services start tomcat
```

and

```
brew services stop tomcat
```

Thanks to Maxime Faye and [this commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/5faab57f3f61d4fc51e128db801195a437ccdcf2).

Run:

```
brew upgrade
```

to obtain this new feature.

Comment: "Use a newer version of the software" is very rarely a useful answer.

Comment: It's not a newer version of tomcat but a newer version of the homebrew formula that allows to use `brew services start tomcat` and `brew services stop tomcat`. Here is the [same question as the OP but in github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/12249). It have been solved and merged into master. Why not to use it?

Comment: tomcat@7 doesn't seem to support this, so you'd have to move to tomcat 9 for this to work.

Comment: Finally found a way to stop this annoying server that runs on 8080 and keeps restarting every time I stop it. Thanks!